# CakePHP 2 - Foreign key to many tables

Tags: cakephp, model, foreign-keys, associations, cakephp-2.0

Please help with model associations.
Schema looks like:
[image: Data model schema]

translation_typeofs.typeof_id is typeof_[name] foreign key

translation_typeofs.typeof_type content part of name of relation table (days, colours, buildings or rooms).

TypeofDays model:

```
class TypeofDay extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'TypeofDay';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'GalleriesTypeofDay' => array(
            'className'  => 'GalleriesTypeofDay',
            'dependent' => true
        ),
        'TranslationTypeof' => array(
            'className'  => 'TranslationTypeof',
            'conditions' => array('TranslationTypeof.typeof_type' => 'days'),
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}
```

TranslationTypeof model:

```
class TranslationTypeof extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'TranslationTypeof';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Language' => array(
            'className'    => 'Language',
            'foreignKey' => 'language_id',
        ),
        'TypeofBuilding' => array(
            'className'  => 'TypeofBuilding',
            'foreignKey' => 'typeof_id',
            'conditions' => array('TranslationTypeof.typeof_type' => 'buildings')
        ),
        'TypeofColour' => array(
            'className'  => 'TypeofColour',
            'foreignKey' => 'typeof_id',
            'conditions' => array('TranslationTypeof.typeof_type' => 'colours')
        ),
        'TypeofRoom' => array(
            'className'  => 'TypeofRoom',
            'foreignKey' => 'typeof_id',
            'conditions' => array('TranslationTypeof.typeof_type' => 'rooms')
        ),
        'TypeofDay' => array(
            'className'  => 'TypeofDay',
            'foreignKey' => 'typeof_id',
            'conditions' => array('TranslationTypeof.typeof_type' => 'days')
        )
    );
}
```

When I try to save data

```
$this->TranslationTypeof->saveAll(array(
    'typeof_type'   => $this->data['type_name'],
    'typeof_id'     => $this->data['type_id'],
    'language_id'   => $languageId,
    'text'          => $translation
));
```

I'm getting error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Error log:

Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`schema`.`translation_typeofs`, CONSTRAINT `translation_typeofs_typeof_buildings_fkid1` FOREIGN KEY (`typeof_id`) REFERENCES `typeof_buildings` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I'm think that it's something with model association, but can't find the solution.

Comment: You are trying to store `typeof_id` let's say `typeof_id=3` then it might not be exist in the foreignKey table.

Comment: Thanks for answer, all ids that I'm trying to add are exist in foreignKey table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `typeof_id` is acting as a foreign key depending on the `typeof_type` provided to it. So there should not be any database foreignKey constraint can be applicable.

So what you can do is: **"Delete the foreignKey constraint from the database using PhpMyAdmin and lets handle it with CakePHP"**. Kindly ask if it not worked for you.